# React Router, access history object from child components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'd like to listen to location change using `history.listen` in one of deep nested child component.

Should the top parent component which has `this.props.history` pass down the props all the way down to the child components?

I'm using 2.8.1 react-router

I am willing to upgrade to newer version if it allows me to do this easily.

Comment: React-router passed the history object  as context to children to deep down leaf node. use context to get history object

Comment: HOW DO IT IN react-router-dom v4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // props also has match, location
    const { history } = this.props;
    ...
  }
}

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get `history` by getting router context.

```js
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';

class myComponent extends React.Component {
   render() {
      console.log(this.context.history);
   }
}

myComponent.contextTypes = {
   history: PropTypes.object
}

export default myComponent;
```

Comment: I think you are using different version, I can't get this.context.history even at the parent component.

Comment: Hm... strange. I've tested this code with 2.8.1. version and it worked. Make sure you've defined `history` in contextTypes and `history` attribute for your <Router> component